# We are no longer Beta!

Tags: discussion

Congratulations to all you expats (and all others). Outside of losing the Beta tag, there won't be any obvious differences... yet. But it is a solid accomplishment. This has been, and will continue to be, the go-to site for long term stay of all kinds, as well as citizenship and other related topics we've adopted. In the coming years we should eventually get some of the customization options available to other fully graduated sites.

Answer (score 2):

Just like to reiterate the thanks to everyone who made this site a success! I have found this site exactly when I moved abroad and a lot of answers - and questions as well - helped me guide through my journey abroad, including my eventual naturalisation.

I'm hoping I'm not the only one who has found the site useful and has gained valuable knowledge, and hopefully it has helped people avoid awkward situations and issues.

Just to also add to what ouflak was saying there are going to be a couple changes apart from losing the Beta flag:

- We're hoping to get a migration path from our big sister site Travel.SE to here. Hopefully this will bring some high quality and useful questions (and potential answers) to this site
- Graduation does mean we will have a real moderator election at some point, either in 2022, or in early 2023. I guess since we had a temporary election not too long ago, we're not in a hurry, but if you would like to try out moderation make sure you volunteer when the opportunity comes.

Thanks again, and hoping for another constructive 7 years, and some more